# How can I run NodeJS and Apache together with an Apache virtual host file on Centos8?

Tags: node.js, apache, websocket, socket.io, webserver

I have my NodeJS application running on example.com:3000. Obviously, this would be unpresentable to have to tell a user to type in :3000. I want it running on example.com, and I cannot set Node to :80 since my Apache PHP front end is on :80.

I am running CentOS 8. I created a file called proxy.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d and dropped the following lines in it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000
</VirtualHost>
```

But, it's just going to my regular non node page.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, how does apache know you when you want the PHP server, or when you want the Node server.  You need to split them by `ServerName`.

You need a `ServerName` attribute so that **apache** knows to send that `VirtualHost` to the other process.

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    // PHP Server
    ServerName example.com www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    // Node Server
    ServerName node.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000
</VirtualHost>
```

Additionally, you will have to put `node.example.com` within DNS.